# Why the Item 'Add Web Reference' was removed from VC 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Why the Item 'Add Web Reference' was removed from VC 2010? And we never can add a web reference to a c++ project in VS 2010.

Is there a reference to microsoft reason for removing this item? where?
Can anybody tell me what is the reason? what is it?

thanks.

Comment: Probably because it's unreliable and prone to abuse and security problems. For reliability, think about what would happen if the link just disappeared? it does happen you know. And what if someone malicious took over the link and inserted malware?

Comment: thank you! Is there a reference to microsoft reason?